# How to Execute asyctask of a public class with parameters and get result from that class after completing the task

Tags: java, android

I want to use this class to pass parameters of name value pair in this asynctask from another fragment class and get that result after completing it.
How to code this task to execute it and get result in another class. please give any hint or suggestions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import com.example.test.R;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ServiceRequest {
    Context c;
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters;
    String actionName;

    public ServiceRequest(Context c, String actionName,
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.c = c;
        this.parameters = params;
        this.actionName = actionName;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getStats() {

        return null;
    }

    class GetStats extends
            AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, String, Map<String, String>> {

        ProgressDialog d;

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> doInBackground(
                ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> list = params[0];
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            d = new ProgressDialog(c, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
            d.setCancelable(false);
            d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            d.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, String> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            d.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i want to use getStats() function to return the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the map as a member of ServiceRequest and when the AsyncTask completes - set the ServiceRequest.map with the results of the task, making it possible for getStats() to return the map.

The problem is that it is, obviously, an asynchronous activity, so whoever calls getStats() might need to call it repeatedly until a value is returned - so you might want to consider publishing the value from your AsyncTask to whoever might use it.

Comment: but how do we know in another class that asyncTask comleted or not.?

Comment: That's why I mentioned that whoever calls getStats() will need to know when to call it (only after a value is available), but in general, this is where the Observer design pattern comes handy: http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/